# Use method to guard class member attribute's type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am fairly new to typescript and was trying to access an optionnal class attribute after calling a function to check whether it is available. The actual check also relies on an other attribute and I'd rather not duplicate code as the check is used in more than one place.

Here is a short example:

```
class Test {
  private ar?: string[];
  public hasArray(): boolean { // Guard here ?
    return !!this.ar;
  }
  public push(s: string) {
    if (this.hasArray()) {
      this.ar.push(s);         // Error
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make this code work by 'documenting' that `this.ar` is available after calling `hasArray` ?

What I tried:

- Replace `public hasArray(): boolean` with `public hasArray(): this.ar is string[]` -> not supported
- Replace `public hasArray(): boolean` with `public hasArray(): this is { ar: string[] }` -> conflicting type error @ `this.ar.push()`

I am aware of the fact that I could turn `if (this.hasArray())` into `if (this.hasArray() && this.ar)`, however it feels more like a gimmick and I was wondering whether someone knew of a way to solve this.

Thanks in advance